# DateTime timezone when format

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

This is a weird issue I have encountered with timezone and DateTime, I`ll keep it short:

```
var_dump($obj->getTime1());
var_dump($obj->getTime2());
```

Gives me the following (which is ok, timezone is good etc..):

```
object(DateTime)#379 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2016-03-28 19:00:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(12) "Europe/Paris"
}
object(DateTime)#378 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2016-03-13 19:00:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(12) "Europe/Paris"
}
```

But when I want to format (on the exact same lines) into string :

```
var_dump($obj->getTime1()->format(DateTime::ISO8601));
var_dump($obj->getTime2()->format(DateTime::ISO8601));
```

I get:

```
string(24) "2016-03-28T19:00:00+0200"  <-- Noticed that it has a different timezone
string(24) "2016-03-13T19:00:00+0100"
```

I hate DateTime

P.S: When I create the 2nd DateTime object I clone the first and I add a DateInterval:

```
 $someTime = clone $obj->getTime1();
 $someTime ->sub(new \DateInterval('P'.$days.'D'));
 $event->setTime2($someTime);
```

Comment: Smells like DST (daylight saving time)...

Comment: also `var_dump($obj->getTime1()->date)`. May be you want this?

Comment: @Anant: I need in `ISO8601` format

Comment: Like @Naruta said, on 2016-03-27 daylight saving will change our distance to GMT with one hour. Your two dates are at different sides of that turning point. The string conversion takes this into account.

Comment: Clocks go forward in Europe for "daylight savings" at 1am on Sunday 27th March

Comment: @Naruto: looolll :)) thanks. Could you please add it as an answer

Comment: So you hate something that is correct, and your first notion is not to question yourself but to hate something that's designed to make your life easier. Man.. this isn't how the whole programming gist works, is it? Things don't happen for no reason in our world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for you getting an extra hour, is because at the last (full) weekend of march, we 'change' timezone, and skip an hour.

This year, this happens on the 27th of March, meaning we are actually getting set in another timezone. DateTime objects automatically do this for you, which is why you are having 2 different timezones.

It will be reversed of the last (full) weekend of October, on the 30 of October.

Answer (score 1):

Since 1999, the European Union has [established](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32000L0084) the following rules for switching from/to Summer time:

- Start: Last Sunday in March
- End: Last Sunday in October

That means that no renewal or prior agreement between countries is required.

Your examples happen to cross the first boundary. In France, that means switching from [CET](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cet) (+0100) to [CEST](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cest) (+0200). PHP takes this into account.

Comment: Thank you for the answer